# Wordpress Media Library

Tags: media-library

How to recuperate my images and photos after accidentally deleted from my Media Library and have disappeared from my website ?
I tried to install wp plugin "add from server" unfortunately impossible to install it and I don't know why?
Please help me found a solution to restore the majority  photos deleted from media library?
Best regards!

Comment: Please [improve your question title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title). Summarize your specific problem, do not include the word WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

Hi unless you've backed up your files there's no other way to retrieve images except for asking your webhost to see if they have a backup. My host does, and keeps it for 30 days before deleting the backup, so that's what I'd try first.

In future, make sure you back up your sites regularly.